# How to resolve failure code -32 runtime exception for media player

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer

I am displaying multiple video in a `ListView` using a `VideoView` like in the vine app.

This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listview;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static int currentItem;
    public static ArrayList<String> videoLIst;
    public static MediaController mediaController ;
    boolean pauseOnScroll = true;
    boolean pauseOnFling = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        System.gc();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build());
        videoLIst = new ArrayList<String>();
         mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this); 
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/165/video/father-and-young-daughter.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/185/video/couple-on-sail-boat.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/39/video/VID-20141231-WA0006.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/26/video/VID-20141216-WA0004.mp4");
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listview.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        listview.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, videoLIst));
        listview.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
         listview.setRecyclerListener(new RecyclerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
                    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

                }
            });

      listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
          private int mFirstVisibleRow = -1;
          private int mActiveItem = -1;

          @Override
          public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
               VideoView videoView = (VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
               if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                   videoView.destroyDrawingCache();
               } else {
                   videoView.buildDrawingCache();
               }
          }


          @Override
          public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                               int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
              int firstVisibleRow = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
              int lastvisiblerow =listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
              if( mFirstVisibleRow != firstVisibleRow )
              {
                  mFirstVisibleRow = firstVisibleRow;

                  // Cancel the video of the previous active item
                  VideoView prevActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem);
                  if( prevActiveVideoView != null )
                  {
                      prevActiveVideoView.pause();
                      prevActiveVideoView.clearAnimation();
//                      prevActiveVideoView.destroyDrawingCache();
                  }

                  // Start the video of the new active item
                  mActiveItem = mFirstVisibleRow + 1;
                  VideoView newActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem);
                  if(newActiveVideoView != null)
                  {
                      newActiveVideoView.start();
//                      newActiveVideoView.buildDrawingCache();

                  }
              }

                  VideoView lastVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(lastvisiblerow);
                  if(lastVideoView != null)
                  {
                      lastVideoView.pause();
                  }

          }

          private VideoView getVideoViewForRow(int row)
          {
              int firstVisibleRow = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
              View rowView = listview.getChildAt(row-firstVisibleRow);
              return (rowView == null) ? null : (VideoView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
          }

      });

    }
    static class ViewHolderItem {

                TextView textViewItem;
                VideoView video;
                ProgressBar progressbar;
            }

    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<String> videoList;

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> videoList) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.videoList = videoList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return videoList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return videoList.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

             Log.d("in getview method:",""+position);
             final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;


             if (convertView == null){
                  inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, null);

                   viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
                   viewHolder.video = (VideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
                   viewHolder.progressbar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

                   viewHolder.textViewItem =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txvposition);


                   int pos;
                   pos=viewHolder.video.getCurrentPosition();
                   Log.d("current item position:",""+pos);
                    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

             }else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();

             }

             viewHolder.textViewItem.setText("Video"+position);
//             mediaController.setAnchorView(viewHolder.video);
             Log.d("video url inadapter:", ""+videoLIst.toString());
             Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoList.get(position));
            // viewHolder.video.setMediaController(mediaController);
           //  viewHolder.video.setVideoURI(uri);
             new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                 @Override
                 public void run() {
//                   viewHolder.video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                   viewHolder.video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     viewHolder.video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoList.get(position)));
                     viewHolder.video.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
            }, 100);
             //viewHolder.video.start();
             viewHolder.video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                     public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer arg0) {
                           viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           viewHolder.video.start();
                           viewHolder.video.setBackgroundResource(0);
                           arg0.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });

                     }
                   });
             viewHolder.video.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {
                      @Override
                       public boolean onInfo(final MediaPlayer mp, final int what, int extra) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         Log.d("BUFFRRING START", "On_InFO");
                         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                         if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START == what) {
                               viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                             Log.d("BUFFRRING START", "" + what);
                         }
                         if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END == what) {
                               viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               Log.d("BUFFRRING END", "" + what);
                         }
                         if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START == what) {
                               viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                               Log.d("RENDERING END", "" + what);
                         }
                             }
                        }, 100);
                         return false;
                       }
                   });
              viewHolder.video.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                       @Override
                       public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                           Log.d("Error", "------>error" + what + "/" + extra);
                           if (extra != 0) {
                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can't Play Video",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }

                           return false;
                       }
                   });
              viewHolder.video.clearAnimation();
              return convertView;           
        }

    }
}
```

Suddenly I am getting this error when scrolling listview and my app is crashes.
Logcat error

```
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908): Process: com.example.videoviewexample, PID: 22908
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908): java.lang.RuntimeException: failure code: -32
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.invoke(MediaPlayer.java:664)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.getInbandTrackInfo(MediaPlayer.java:1697)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.scanInternalSubtitleTracks(MediaPlayer.java:1856)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.access$600(MediaPlayer.java:529)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2203)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-25 12:05:03.802: E/AndroidRuntime(22908):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I too have same isssue,Did you found any solution

Answer (score 0):

```
viewHolder.video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
   public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
      mp.setDisplay(null);
      mp.reset();
      mp.setDisplay(getHolder());
   }
});
```

This should reset the MediaPlayer and avoid the issue. If you're still seeing this issue after adding this code let me know.